# Audio not playing in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, image

My audio object is not playing in react. I do not want to use the html audio tag because I have custom styling for the audio controls. Also if this did get this working would the audio restart after re-rendering?

```
  render() {
    const myaudio = new Audio(require("./sound.mp3"))
    myaudio.play();
    myaudio.loop = true;

    return (
      //html
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the `require` simply do:

```
const myAudio = new Audio("sound.mp3");
```

This should work if you are running on a web server (not a local file), but if you access your react app via the webpack dev server you should be okay